# a javascript question about destructuring when [a, b] = [b ,a]

Tags: javascript

I met a confuse problem when i use destructuring in javascript.
Here is the code:

```js
let a = 1
let b = 2
[b, a] = [a, b]
console.log([a, b])
```

I expect that variables a and b will exchange their value, but here throw a error, which is "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'b' before initialization". I cannot figure out why this happens.

Comment: Don't rely on Automatic Semicolon Insertion unless you're *really sure* of what you're doing

Comment: In this code it will not insert semicolon at end of `let b = 2` and will consider let `b = 2[b,a]`. `[b,a]` acts as bracket notaion.

Comment: thx! I get it. Missing semicolon results in this situation;